# how to add custom trace message inside webmethod in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, asmx, trace, webmethod

I have already added the `trace.warn` message inside the `Page_Load` event of my ASP.net website and able to view the custom tracing messages.

Similarly added custom trace message inside a webmethod

```
[WebMethod]
public static object Save(string data)
{
  HttpContext.Current.Trace.Warn("Start Save Method :");
}
```

But it is not giving any trace information. What could be the reason? or how can I implement tracing inside this method and on which section of Trace Information I can see this trace message?

Comment: Not certain of the reason, but keep in mind that your `[WebMethod]` is not actually associated with a page.

Comment: @ John Saunders: you are right.But i need to monitor the performance

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you only use tracing at asp.net page level `<%@ Page Language="C#" Trace="true"  %>` ?

In this case you have to enable tracing [globally](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x5wc973%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in your web.config file:

```
<trace enabled="true" pageOutput="false" requestLimit="40" localOnly="false"/>
```

Then you can access the information via the Page `http://localhost:<portnumber>/trace.axd` in the section Trace Information for each request.

I just tested. It is working for warn/write on aspx pages and webmethods.

Comment: me too tried the same.But not got any trace message for web method which is associated with button click

Comment: And HttpContext.Current.Trace.Write("Write"); is working ?